# How to bypass file access in linux kernel

Tags: file, io, linux-kernel

I have a linux kernel (more exactly an Android kernel) that creates a sysfs entry to read data from a connected device. Output yields raw data.

Now I want to create a new file interface in procfs that reads this data and outputs it in another format.

The first idea is to access the sysfs file because it returns exactly what I need as input to my function. Now I read kernels should not do file operations.
But what else is the recommended way? Digging into the device driver and copying all that happens in there would be tedious.

Comment: Recommended way is to perform file's content conversion **in the user space** and do not touch kernel code at all. `I read kernels should not do file operations.` - perfoming I/O operation in the kernel space is not recommended, but you may use it if needed. As you don't want to digging into the device driver code, how else you expect to get needed data?

Comment: The driver presents the raw content in a procfs file. The easiest way is to read this file, so no driver specific things must be copied.